# How do I select the attack angle when using a skulljack?

Tags: xcom-2

I can choose which direction to use the Ranger's Slash from with the mouse, but using a skulljack activates the GUI where you can't seem to change the attack direction.

How do I choose the attack direction?

Comment: I'll have to check this, but I was thinking you could aim the skulljack like the sword if you had a non-ranger using it. Maybe not.

Answer (score 6):

As of the May 2016 patch (released at the same time as the Alien Hunters DLC), this user interface is a big better. You select the action like Skullmine, and each of the spaces around the targeted enemy from where the attack is valid (not the far side of a solid wall) will be highlighted in yellow. **Left**-click on one of those spaces and the soldier will run to that spot then perform the skulljack attack.

Answer (score 4):

In the vanilla base game, you can't.

Unfortunate as it is, you can rest easy that the automatically picked angle *often* is in cover, and is *generally* in the direction you're approaching from.

Comment: It's very odd that players are given immense flexibility in terms of how to execute a Ranger sword attack, yet can't do anything similar with the Skulljack, which is basically another melee attack that functions identically.

Comment: This might be obvious, but if you don't have to sprint all the way to the target (or if you have RUn & Gun), then you can just move next to them in the spot you want and skulljack from there.

Comment: Is there a good mod for it then?

Comment: @nwod not that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Also remember - if you miss, you get another action; if you hit you kill.  So in the right set of circumstances, it might not even matter if you aren't in the spot you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the base game you can't choose the attack like you can do with a sword attack.

Even with sword attacks, once you choose sword attack you cannot switch the angle anymore, instead you just have to position the cursor and wait for the sword icon to appear towards the enemy in order to attack from that angle, which is a bit stupid anyway.

Nevertheless you can always position yourself next to the enemy, wherever you want and then use skulljack attack.

**It helps a lot if you have Run&Gun!**  Especially if you are fortunate enough for a specialist of yours to get Run&Gun (Hidden Ability). That's when you know this is gonna be the best campaign :)